# Git adding duplicate files into the repo

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have this file called `readme.html` in my git Repo.

Its been there since 10 months, Have not touched it.

Today I worked with other files and did a `git add --all`, committed and pushed the new version.

The `readme.html` was not changed but I have this file called `readme.4ead5bd97d0927ddb88f8f672067910a.html`.

It has the same contents as `readme.html`.

How to deal with this and any idea why this happened ?

Comment: does only readme filename changed, or many other files ?

Comment: Just the readme file.

Comment: Never use `git add --all`, for exactly this reason. You should care more about the things you are pushing into your repository. Use `git add -p` and `git add -i` and actually *review* the changes you're making.

Comment: I understand thanks @meagar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tool has generated it as a backup or for some other reasons.

You can simply remove this file withe those commands:

```bash
# remove and commit the file
rm readme.4ead5bd97d0927ddb88f8f672067910a.html
git rm --cached readme.4ead5bd97d0927ddb88f8f672067910a.html

# just verify that  the file will be deleted
git add -A .
git status

# commit the deletion of the file
git commit -m "Deleted readme.4ead5bd97d0927ddb88f8f672067910a.html"

git push origin <branch>
```

Comment: Or just `git rm readme.4ead5bd97d0927ddb88f8f672067910a.html`?

Comment: You also have to remove it from the repo itself (history) , this is why you have to rm from the cache as well.

Comment: Cool. Thank you for accepting the answer. you can also vote for it if you like. Glad to help.

Comment: You can also read this answer to learn how to revert the commits/tags if needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Git. You inadvertently created that file outside of Git, at some point in history, and added it by doing `git add --all`.